# Writing out a string in Cobol and would like to mask the first 6 digits of an accout number with all X's?

Tags: cobol

I am having to write out a bank account number in Cobol. The user of the report would like all of the account numbers but the last four X's. My data structure is as follows.

Data Structure:

```
        01 Account.
           05 acct   pic x(10) value spaces.
```

Print out:

```
        XXXXXX5678
```

I have tried the following:

```
        01 Account.
           05 six-digits pic x(06) value 'XXXXXX'.
           05 four-digits pic x(04) value spaces.

 MOVE new-account-value TO Accout.   -- this over writes the X's and screws up my printout
 WRITE E-Record FROM Account.
```

What would be an easy way of doing this simple operation? Cobol always seems to have a bit of a glitch to it.

New Code: (Still does not work)
why would this be the case. This is like the example and I think if I recall that the value all keeps the X as constants but this might be were I have gone wrong.

```
02  BANK-INFORMATIONE.                             
     04  H5-ROUTE.                                  
         10 ROUTE-UNUSED PIC X(09) VALUE ALL 'X'.   
         10 ROUTE-USED   PIC X(04) VALUE SPACES.    
     04  FILLER   PIC XX      VALUE SPACES.         
     04  H5-ACCTE.                                  
         10 ACCT-UNUSED PIC X(06) VALUE ALL 'X'.    
         10 ACCT-USED   PIC X(04) VALUE SPACES.
```

Comment: Is ROUTE-UNUSED support to be nine bytes? What PROCEDURE DIVISION code did you write?

Comment: Yes, the unused is supossed to be nine bytes. When you refer to the procedure division do you need to see all of that code. If I move X to route-unused just before I write then it works but I thought that Value All was similar to a constant and did not need to be rewriten.

Comment: COBOL only has constants in the sense that that is what they are if you don't change them. Have you used INITIALIZE or otherwise set BANK-INFORMATIONE to some value? What output are you actually getting when it doesn't work. Six spaces followed by the desired four digits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    01 Account-Reference.
       05  acct-to-ignore   pic x(6).
       05  acct-to-use      pic x(4).

    01 Masked-Account.
       05  Masked-Account-Mask PIC X(6) VALUE ALL "X".
       05  Masked-Account-Data PIC X(4).

 MOVE acct-to-use TO Masked-Account-Data
 WRITE E-Record FROM Masked-Account
```

It is then clear what everything is to the next person reading the program.

I recommend avoiding single-word datanames. You never know if a word you've chosen may later become a "reserved word" to the compiler and it is less descriptive.

Going through your question again, if it is for a report, or is a report, rather than a file going somewhere, just define a literal containing six X's (as above) followed by the four bytes on the report line itself. If you are writing out the account to a file to report on later, there is no need to include the X's on the file itself. So you could just use the four low-order digits that you need.

Comment: @Doug Hauf This is the best answer because the full account number is truncated during the `MOVE`. This means the full number can never be moved into the report record. If during future maintenance someone forgets to blow away the first
six digits of ACCOUNT (as other answers require) the full account number might be published - not a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

```
MOVE new-account-value TO Account

MOVE 'XXXXXX' TO Account(1:6)

WRITE E-Record FROM Account
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
    01 Account.
       05 six-digits pic x(06).
          88 Account-X value 'XXXXXX'.
       05 four-digits pic x(04).

MOVE new-account-value TO Account
SET Account-X to true
WRITE E-Record FROM Account
```

The 88 level definition for the first 6 digits of Account will
do the overwrite for you. The VALUE clause you were using is only
ever set once on initial program load (not by the INITIALIZE statement), so once you move any value
to Account it is lost and cannot be reset.

Or the other obvious solution might be:

```
MOVE new-account-value TO Account
MOVE 'XXXXXX' to six-digits
WRITE E-Record FROM Account
```

And finally, the solution proposed by Moot will work too.

Answer (score 1):

@Moot answer should work fine.

Another solution would be

```
01  Account PIC X(010).
01  FILLER REDEFINES Account.
    03 HiddenPart PIC X(006).
    03 ShownPart PIC X(004).


MOVE new-account-value to Account.
MOVE ALL "X" TO HiddenPart.
WRITE E-Record FROM Account.
```